# ProgressBar WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá , vi vários exemplos na internet de progressBar no WPF , porém nenhum funciona.

Ele aparece mais não preenche os valores, na verdade ele preenche os valores somente após execução do método inicial aonde é chamado.

Código fonte:

```
 public partial class Apresentacao_ProgressBar : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Apresentacao_ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Form1_Shown);

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {            
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);              
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: O evento `Form1_Shown` está sendo chamado quando o form é aberto?

Comment: O evento está sendo chamado sim.

Answer (score 1):

1 - `BackgroundWorker`está meio em desuso atualmente.

2 - Use MVVM quando trabalhar com WPF, ele foi feito para funcionar perfeitamente com esse modelo.

3 - Para funcionar o ProgressBar você precisa que o trabalho dele seja feito em outro thread (o `BackgroundWorker` faz isso mas como disse ta em desuso)

segue um exemplo:

```
private Task _task;

public string Arquivo
{
    get => _arquivo;
    set
    {
        if (value == _arquivo) return;
        _arquivo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public double ProgressMax
{
    get => _progressMax;
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_progressMax)) return;
        _progressMax = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public double ProgressValue
{
    get => _progressValue;
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_progressValue)) return;
        _progressValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void Importar(string arquivo = "")
{
    //Minhas verificações e outras coisas que não preciso mostrar

    ProgressValue = 0;

    //Aqui verifico se o arquivo está ok (no meu projeto o arquivo vem de um download, 
    //   então não preciso verificar aqui se ele existe pois o serviço de download já verifica)

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) return;  //fileName é uma variavel com um arquivo a ser importado
    try
    {
        if ((_task != null) && (_task.IsCompleted == false ||
                                _task.Status == TaskStatus.Running ||
                                _task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun ||
                                _task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation))
            return;  //se já houver um thread para essa variavel _task ele não inicia outro

        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(TratarArquivo);  //Inicia o Thread
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExibirMensagem(Uteis.RetornaMsgErro(e), TipoMensagem.Erro);
    }

}

private void TratarArquivo()
{
    try
    {
        ProgressVisibility = true;

        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;


        var dados = LeArquivo(Arquivo);

        ProgressMax = dados.Count();

        foreach (var linha in dados)
        {
            ProgressValue = j;
            j++;
            //Aqui tem várias coisas que são tratadas, nao importa nesse exemplo
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExibirMensagem(Uteis.RetornaMsgErro(e), TipoMensagem.Erro);
    }
    finally
    {
        ProgressVisibility = false;
        ProgressValue = 0;
    }
}
```

P.S.: Caso não entenda o porque das propriedades implementarem OnPropertyChanged() procure saber mais sobre MVVM e `INotifyPropertyChanged`

P.S.: Esses dados são da classe `ImportacaoViewModel`, eu NÃO tenho nenhuma linha adicionada ao code behind

P.S.: Caso queria um exemplo completo, porém muito simples, de como fazer me mande um email celsolivero.no.gmail.com